# Send a received file throught a service, without save it and pipe it with express js and busboy

Tags: node.js, express, request, busboy

I have a service, what receive a post request with a file and json data too. I use the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) package either in the app.js. I want to send the file to a "filer" service, and process the answer from that, but I don't want to pipe the request, because I need to process the json content too and make some actions after the filer answered.

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const request = require('request');

const sendFile = (req, file, callback) => {
  return request.post({
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/stream',
    headers: req.headers,
    formData: { value: file }
  }, (err, resp, body) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return callback();
  });
};

app.post('/route', (req, res, next) {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  busboy.on('file', (fieldName, file) => {
    file.on('error', err => reject(err));
    return sendFile(req, file, (err, link) => {
      file.resume();
      if (err) return reject(err);
    });
  });

  busboy.on('field', (fieldName, val) => {
    // process the json here...
  });

  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('busboy.on(finish)');
    return next();
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

The filer service the following:

```
app.post('/stream', (req, res, next) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  // here we are ok
  busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, file, name) {
    // but this part never run
    res.send(200, { fileId: fileDoc._id });
  });

  return req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Unfortunatelly the filer service never answer, and I don't know, where is a missing part. Tried to put the `file.resume()` to some places inside the `busboy.on('file')`, but doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the file stream from busboy is never processed properly by request formData.

Another way is:

1. Temporarily write the stream to a local file in main service.(using `fs.createWriteStream`)
2. Create a stream from that file and pipe it to filer service.(using `fs.createReadStream`)
3. Do whatever processing you need to do in main service.
4. Wait for response from filer service and call `next()`

This way you can even use the file in main service if you need to or send the file to another service.

Comment: I try to avoid to store the files on local, this load is unneccesary. Mostly because I don't have anything to modify in the file.

Comment: I believe the issue with stream from busboy being used in formdata. formData for requestjs, probably isn't recognizing it as a valid file stream. I have had this issue. The only other thing you could do is pipe this stream to request directly and then on close event callback.